# UIDatePicker, dates beyond maximum and minimum are still visible

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

The reference for [UIDatePicker.maximumDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615999-maximumdate) says the following:

> **maximumDate**
>
> The maximum date that a date picker **can show.**

The reference for [minimumDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615980-minimumdate) says the equivalent for minimum.

But when implementing maximumDate and minimumDate in an `UIDatePicker`, the picker still **shows** the maximum and the minimum dates. And way more. Actually, the `UIDatePicker` shows ALL dates. The only thing that has changed is that when you stop scrolling, it automatically scrolls you back to the min/max threshold.
Is there a way to prevent dates before minimumDate and dates after maximumDate to ever appear? If I set the `maximumDate` to January 1st 2020, I don't want/need the user to be able to scroll beyond that just to be thrown back to this date. They can sit there scrolling and scrolling for minutes/hours if they want, and end up in the year 3000. And when they stop scrolling, it will revert to 2020. Why? I want the date picker to NOT SHOW the dates beyond min/max, and literally stop there. No more dates outside my range.
I know this is possible with `UIPicker`, if I create it myself, but I feel this should be the default behavior when implementing min/max in this element.

Why is this not possible with `UIDatePicker`? Or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but UIDatePicker doesn't support setting valid date ranges like you describe. The only option is prepare an array from calendar dates then pass it to picker.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with UIDatePicker. I suggest implementing your own date picker by using an UIPickerView and populating the custom values.

Comment: Yeah, not gonna do that. Too much time for such a tiny feature. We use the datePicker several places, and with different configurations (e.g showing days/hours/minutes etc.), so I'd have to create populations for all these as well. I'd rather stick to the native behavior, since it's not bad practice.

Comment: @Sti Yes! Native behavior is always the best. As most of the users are already familiar with that.